# Can the login screen be a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I create an application that will have a home screen, a login screen for one of the functions and a screen for this function. Should I only take the main screen as aсtivity, and the login and function screen as fragments, or everything as activity? And if more than one aсtivity, can I use nav graph?
At first, I wanted to create only one activity, but I'm not sure if the login screen can be a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you should use single activity. You could have many fragments and navigate between them using the [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation).